# PHP: Trigger a Method and ignore the returning content

Tags: php, class, oop, exit, ob-start

my first own question on Stackoverflow!

First of all: Thank you for your help, and sorry for my bad english. ^^

I try to get the values, which a child class method gives his parent class method. The problem is, 
that the parent class method terminates the current script with `exit;` + I don't have access to the 
child class(es) + I don't want to edit the 'one class' (see below).

The code, for a better understanding:

```
<?php
    // The Controller
    class one{
        // [...]
        public $classVAR = "";
        public $classVAR2 = "";

        public function render($param1, $param2){
            // This are the variables that I need.
            $this->classVAR = $param1;
            $this->classVAR2 = $param2;

            return new View(); // Returns the Page Content
        }

        public function display($param1, $param2, $exit = true){
            echo $this->render($param1, $param2);

            if($exit === true){
                exit;
            }
        }
        // [...]
    }

    // Another Class to which I have no control (ex. "Plugin Classes")
    class two extends one{
        // [...]
        public function index(){
            // Some other Stuff

            //  string  $stuff
            //  array   $otherstuff
            $this->display($stuff, $otherstuff);
        }
        // [...]
    }
?>
```

## Try 1 :: With the ReflectionClass

I tried to read the content of the index method, inside the "two class".

So i catched the source of the index function, and seperated the parameters inside the 
`$this->display` method call.

Problem: The `$otherstuff` variable contains - in the most cases - an array with one (or more) 
"key=>option" pairs, which can be used by the View Class. And the "two class", which i used for this 
experiment, contains the pair `'something' => $this->loadOptions()`, and this method was protected.

## Try 2 :: With ob_start()

I tried to load the content, which returns from the View Class, in the buffer. But the `exit;` command 
breaks the php code completely and prints the output directly (and i don't want the output from the 
'View' Class).

The code:

```
class myclass extends one{
    public function myfunc(){
        ob_start();
            $something = new two();
            $something->index();
        ob_end_clean();

        $param1 = $this->classVAR;
        $param2 = $this->classVAR2;
    }
}
```

## Thoughts

Is it possible to call the index method (of the "two class") temporary, without a completely break 
through the `exit;` line?

Or is it possible to load the "two" class in the buffer and then to manipulate the `$this->display` 
method? If yes, then i could add a third parameter, which would disable the `exit;` line.

Or is it possible to "change" the parent of the two class?

Have You any other idea, how i can solve this problem? But please without experimental PHP Codes, 
or additional PHP extensions / libraries.

**Thank You!**
(I hope I could explain my problem well.)

Sincerely Yours,
Sam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try to set the default value of $exit to false ?

```
class one{
    //...

     public function display($param1, $param2, $exit = false){
        // ...
    }
}
```

how about - Second Option ?

custom class extends the **two** class

```
class myclass extends two{

    public function display($param1, $param2, $exit = false){
        parent::display($param1, $param2, $exit);
    }
}

$something = new myclass();
$something->index();
```

Comment: Yes, but i don't want to edit the one class. 

This project is a plugin for a CMS and the 'one class' is a part of it. I don't want, that the users of this plugin needs to modify a system class.

Thanks, for your Answer.

Comment: **Thank you!** It works perfectly! I would upvote your comment, but i have not enough reputations, sorry. ^^ But, thank you!

Comment: No prob... maybe later ;)

Comment: 2 Years later ... I got enough points to upvote your comment! xD